# arrayMaxConsecutiveSum c#

Tags: c#, arrays

As part of learning c# I engage in codesignal challenges. So far everything is going good for me, except for the test stated in the title.

The problem is that my code is not efficient enough to run under 3 seconds when the length of an array is 10^5 and the number of consecutive elements (k) is 1000. My code runs as follows:

```
int arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(int[] inputArray, int k) {

    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= inputArray.Length-k; i++)
    {
        sum = inputArray.Skip(i).Take(k).Sum();

        if (sum > max)
            max = sum;
    }

    return max;
}
```

All visible tests in the website run OK, but when it comes to hidden test, in test 20, an error occured, stating that

> 19/20 tests passed. Execution time limit exceeded on test 20: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

I also tried unlocking solutions but on c# the code is somewhat similar to this but he didn't use LINQ. I also tried to run it together with the hidden tests but same error occurred, which is weird as how it was submitted as a solution when it didn't even passed all tests.

Is there any faster way to get the sum of an array?

I also thought of unlocking the hidden tests, but I think it won't give me any specific solution as the problem would still persists.

Comment: You will need to use an `O(N)` algorithm to solve this, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that you are doing the addition of k numbers for every loop.  This pseudo code should be more efficient:

1. Take the sum of the first k elements and set this to be the max.
2. Loop as you had before, but each time subtract from the existing sum the element at i-1 and add the element at i + k.
3. Check for max as before and repeat.

---

The difference here is about the number of additions in each loop.  In the original code you add k elements for every loop, in this code, within each loop you subtract a single element and add a single element to an existing sum, so this is 2 operations versus k operations.  Your code starts to slow down as k gets large for large arrays.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks. Still confused as how separating the first 3 elements made the code run efficiently. I would also like to upvote this, unfortunately I still have less than 15 reputation

Comment: @Dorokun192 it comes down to time complexity, yours is O(n*k), this one is, O(n)

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, I would suggest you not to use `Skip` method as it iterates on the collection every time. You can check the `Skip` implementation at [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L633). Copying the code for reference.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return SkipIterator<TSource>(source, count);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext()) count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
                while (e.MoveNext()) yield return e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see `Skip` iterates the collection everytime, so if you have a huge collection with `k` as a high number, than you can see the execution time sluggish.

Instead of using `Skip`, you can write simple `for` loop which iterates required items:

```
public static int arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(int[] inputArray, int k) 
{

    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= inputArray.Length-k; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < k + i; j++)
        {
            sum += inputArray[j];
        }

        if (sum > max)
            max = sum;
    }
    return max;
}
```

You can check this dotnet fiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/RrUmZX where you can compare the time difference. For through benchmarking, I would suggest to look into [Benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Comment: Both will have a time complexity of O(n*k) it only needs to be O(n)

Comment: @TheGeneral - got it. This can be done by O(n) as suggested by Paddy by two pointer approach.

Comment: using dotnetfiddle, my previous code gave me a memory of 1.67Mb, with execute time of 0.328s. I now see the large difference with the new code, which runs at Last Run: 4:46:04 pm
Compile: 0.156s
Execute: 0s
Memory: 813kb
CPU: 0s

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when using LINQ and thinking about performance. Not that it's slow, but that it can easily hide a big operation behind a single word. In this line:

```
sum = inputArray.Skip(i).Take(k).Sum();
```

`Skip(i)` and `Take(k)` will both take approximately as long as a `for` loop, stepping through thousands of rows, and that line is run for every one of the thousands of items in the main loop.

There's no magic command that is faster, instead you have to rethink your approach to do the minimum of steps inside the loop. In this case you could remember the sum from each step and just add or remove individual values, rather than recalculating the whole thing every time.

```
public static int arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(int[] inputArray, int k) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= inputArray.Length-k; i++)
    {
        // Add the next item
        sum += inputArray[i];

        // Limit the sum to k items
        if (i > k) sum -= inputArray[i-k];

        // Is this the highest sum so far?
        if (sum > max)
            max = sum;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
public int ArrayMaxConsecutiveSum(int[] inputArray, int k)
{
    int max = inputArray.Take(k).Sum();
    int sum = max;

    for (int i = 1; i <= inputArray.Length - k; i++)
    {
        sum = sum - inputArray[i- 1] + inputArray[i + k - 1];

        if (sum > max)
            max = sum;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should never run take & skip on large lists but here's a purely LINQ based solution that is both easy to understand and performs the task in sufficient time.  Yes iterative code will still outperform it so you have to take the trade off for your use case.  Benchmarks because of size or easy to understand

```cs
int arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(int[] inputArray, int k)
{
    var sum = inputArray.Take(k).Sum();
    return Math.Max(sum, Enumerable.Range(k, inputArray.Length - k)
        .Max(i => sum += inputArray[i] - inputArray[i - k]));
}
```